# Статус checkbox сразу после нажатия

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток.

Внутри `div` есть несколько `label` с `checkbox` и `span`. В оригинале сами чекбоксы скрыты - есть только span по которому можно кликнуть и повлиять через него на чекбокс.

С помощью jquery я пытаюсь найти все отмеченные чекбоксы. И если найден хоть один - заношу его класс в массив.

Проблема - всё работает с запаздыванием в один клик. Если кликнуть по чекбоксу, то jquery отрабатывает быстрее, чем чекбокс отметится. Как это решить? Понимаю, что можно: при нажатии на span посмотреть в каком состоянии связанный с ним sheckbox. Если не нажат, то в скрипте будем считать, что он нажат и т.п. Но это перекруты какие-то... Можно ли это как-то обычно сделать?

```js
jQuery("span").click(function(event) {
  my_arr = new Array();
  jQuery('#all input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    my_arr.push($(this).attr('class'));
    return false;
  });
  console.log(my_arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='all'>
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="hull" value="to92">
     <span class="hull">to92</span>
  </label>
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="hull" value="to91">
     <span class="hull">to91</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery("input:checkbox").change(function(event) {
  my_arr = [];
  jQuery('#all input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    my_arr.push($(this).attr('class'));
    return false;
  });
  console.log(my_arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='all'>
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="hull" value="to92">
     <span class="hull">to92</span>
  </label>
  <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="filter" class="hull" value="to91">
     <span class="hull">to91</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! простофиля я) Чрез пару минут отмечу вопрос как решённый.

Comment: @n.osennij Не за что. Зато вопрос хорошо задан. Удачи.